# Display list of products in a grid fashion in MVC as shown in ecommerce websites

Tags: .net, user-interface, model-view-controller, e-commerce

I am fetching list of product from database and want to display them in 3X4 grid (not as a list through gridview) for my ecommerce project, as shown in image
[Amazon Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kv10Z.png)

I want to implement paginations too so that I should display only limited items.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, Your question is too broad in order to have a faster answer you'll have to be more specific e.g: what have you tried? do you have some code? There are a bunch of posts explain how gridviews work. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I don't have any clue how to achieve it so i do not have any code.I just want to know is there any htlm control like listview or api which i can use to iterate the objects in the list which i will pass to the view and put each object in grids

Comment: Well, that said, you can use basic HTML, and use a CSS library like bootstrap which has a simple grid system, give it a try: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid, there are some examples in bootsnipp that you can us https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/crowdfunding-grid, let me know if you need more help, I can write a general example of how it would be done with MVC.

Comment: @nramirez I am using bootstrap 4 , but now my doubt is how to implement pagination or "load more".I can think of pagination in a table but not sure how to do it in a grid system.

Comment: since the answer resolves your initial problem you can accept the answer. for pagination, you can use Ajax and move this logic to Javascript, rendering should be straight forward with this basic logic, but you'll have to create an API action in MVC so you can request new products every time the page changes. Give it a try to this, However, this is not the most efficient way to display this type of grid, you might be interested in using a framework like https://vuejs.org/ or https://facebook.github.io/react/ since this will be more efficient and easier for displaying this HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of products, then using MVC and Bootstrap you can do the following:

```
@model Products[]

<div class="container-fluid">
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Length; i += 4)
    {
        <div class="row">
            @for (var j = i; j < i + 4; j++)
            {
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="@Model[j].Url" alt="...">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h3>@Model[j].Label</h3>
                            <p>@Model[j].Description</p>
                            <p>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Add Cart</a> <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">View</a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>


    }
</div>
```

You can find more info about what you can do with Bootstrap here http://getbootstrap.com/css/

I used the grid system http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

And the thumbnails: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#thumbnails